# Bootstrap Responsive Design - move panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel, responsive

Is there anyway to "move" a panel before another?

For instance I have 3 panels:

```
<div id="left" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

        <a href="mail-compose.html" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-compose-email">Left</a>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel content


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 <div id="mid" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

        <a href="mail-compose.html" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-compose-email">Mid</a>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel content


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 <div id="right" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

        <a href="mail-compose.html" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-compose-email">Right</a>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel content


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

What I would like to do is when the phone reaches

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {  }
```

I want to make my 2 col-xs-6 panels [left and right] to be next to each other and then mid will be under them since it is a col-xs-12

I tried adding a

```
#left {float:left;}
#right {float:left;}
```

inside the phone media so that I could try and force them to float next to each other but it didn't work.

Is this even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can use display flex property on xs devices.
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBYGxL?editors=1100)

```
@media(max-width:768px){
  #right
  {
  float:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

2. Or you can create another mid div after right div and show it only on xs devices, while keeping the first mid div hidden on xs devices only. know more about hidden-* and visible-* bootstrap classes [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide).
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqOxJm?editors=1000)

Comment: I duplicated the div and hidden/unhid it. Thanks that worked fine